# Convert #define from bytes to string

Tags: c

I am working with some example project for BLE connecting, the part of code looks like this:

```
#define UUID_BASE "\xaa\x82\xe0\x12\x69\xa2\x4b\xe7\x93\xe4\x19\xc9\x00\x00\x00\x00"

#define USER_ADVERTISE_SCAN_RESPONSE_DATA ("\x10"\UUID_BASE)

const struct data_struct
= {

    .
    .
    .APP_BLE_ADV_DATA              = USER_ADVERTISE_DATA,
    .APP_BLE_SCAN_RESP_DATA        = USER_ADVERTISE_SCAN_RESPONSE_DATA,
    .
    .
  }
```

I want to represent the UUID_BASE like this:

```
#define UUID_BASE 0xaa, 0x82, 0xe0, 0x12, 0x69, 0xa2,0x4b, 0xe7, 0x93, 0xe4, 0x19, 0xc9, 0x00, 0x00,0x00,0x00
```

My question is, how can i convert my representation of UUID_BASE in bytes to their representation by string, that i can continue with their code as is.

I'd really appreciate your help. I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Thank you!!!

Comment: I don't see an option to do this directly without any for loop or similar.

Comment: How it should be done, depends on how you are going to use it. Please explain in code what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also, why are data bytes different? Is that related to your problem? Your question is unclear, please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Any reason why you have different data in the two examples?

Comment: I am using some project example for the ble connecting, in this code, they are using the "string representation" of this UUID_BASE and then are putting it to scan response data like this: 
// Scan response data
#define USER_ADVERTISE_SCAN_RESPONSE_DATA ("\x11"\
                                              ADV_TYPE_COMPLETE_LIST_128BIT_SERVICE_IDS\
                                           UUID_BASE)
I am using the "byte representation of UUID_BASE" and i need to convert it to their representation for putting it to the scan response data.

Comment: Don't explain in comments, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: The data needs to be the same, my mistake.

Comment: How do you use `USER_ADVERTISE_SCAN_RESPONSE_DATA`? What is `ADV_TYPE_COMPLETE_LIST_128BIT_SERVICE_IDS`?

Comment: Maybe you should also add why your define is given like this. I doubt this is given as constant directly in the code like this (otherwise you could just write it the other way), so it probably comes from outside. So why not just change the preprocessing?

Comment: In the example project they are putting the USER_ADVERTISE_SCAN_RESPONSE_DATA to some const struct. 

#define ADV_TYPE_COMPLETE_LIST_128BIT_SERVICE_IDS           "\x07" 
This is some const parameter in "string representation " too.

Comment: Please make this easier for us. Make [mcve]. A smallest possible complete program that demonstrates the problem. In this case it would throw a compiler error.  Right now we are wasting time guessing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please read the link I gave you. Your example is minimal, but **not complete or verifiable**. We cannot compile it. We stil don't know, `struct data_struct` or `APP_BLE_SCAN_RESP_DATA`. You need to add less than 10 lines to make it complete, and solution would most likely be obvious. Pulling this information from you as we are doing now is extremely frustrating!

Comment: I already accepted the answer to my question from koalo, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write it like this

```
#define UUID_BASE 0xaa, 0x82, 0xe0, 0x12, 0x69, 0xa2, 0x4b, 0xe7, 0x93, 0xe4, 0x19, 0xc9, 0xb2, 0xaf
#define USER_ADVERTISE_SCAN_RESPONSE_DATA {0x10, UUID_BASE, 0x0}
```

The reason is, that apart from the terminating `\0`, the data is identical as soon as you put it into an array.

This code

```
#define UUID_BASE 0xaa, 0x82, 0xe0, 0x12, 0x69, 0xa2, 0x4b, 0xe7, 0x93, 0xe4, 0x19, 0xc9, 0xb2, 0xaf
char dataA[] = {UUID_BASE, 0x0};
```

is completely equivalent to this code

```
#define UUID_BASE_STR "\xaa\x82\xe0\x12\x69\xa2\x4b\xe7\x93\xe4\x19\xc9\xb2\xaf"
char dataB[] = UUID_BASE_STR;
```

You can test it like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define UUID_BASE_BYTES 0xaa, 0x82, 0xe0, 0x12, 0x69, 0xa2, 0x4b, 0xe7, 0x93, 0xe4, 0x19, 0xc9, 0xb2, 0xaf
#define UUID_BASE_STR "\xaa\x82\xe0\x12\x69\xa2\x4b\xe7\x93\xe4\x19\xc9\xb2\xaf"

int main() {
    char dataA[] = {UUID_BASE_BYTES, 0x0};
    char dataB[] = UUID_BASE_STR;

    if(strcmp(dataA,dataB) == 0) {
        printf("The strings are equal\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("The strings are not equal\n");
    }
}
```

This outputs `The strings are equal`

Comment: @user694733 Obviously I do not made my point clear. What I was trying to say is that as soon as you use these defines to fill in an array, you do not have to worry about the difference, the data duplication is just to show that these approaches are in fact equal.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not what i asked to solve. I changed my question a little. I hope, now it is clear.

Comment: @Antonio Maybe this IS what you asked. I guess you actually do not want a preprocessor string, but want to assign it to an array. Please see my edit! Otherwise, please provide the definition of `struct data_struct`

Comment: @Antonio If this does not answer your question, your question is very very unclear. You have presented 2 ways to represent the same data. One is a C string, one is a byte array. These are defined at compile time. You either use the version with a string, or you use the version with a byte array that koalo has presented to you. If you want to convert your byte array to a string, you do so yourself, by hand and type it into your source code. If you somehow need to do this conversion at runtime, you need to say so very clearly in your question. (but, doing so at runtime doesn't really make sense)